# UWP DevCenter recognized not all languages

Tags: uwp

I have an uwp app and added three resource files, one for english (en), german (de) and russian (ru). But the store shows me as langues: German, Germany - Germany and English. Where does the German - Germany come from  and why is russian not recognized?

[image]

[image]

I tried aswell to rename the folders to de-DE, en-US and ru-RU but that didn't change something.

Neutral language is set to en.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The languages are automatically generated (somehow, who knows how).

You can manually specify the languages in appxmanifest. Change it from

```
<Resources>
  <Resource Language="x-generate" />
</Resources>
```

To

```
<Resources>
  <Resource Language="de" />
  <Resource Language="en" />
  <Resource Language="ru" />
</Resources>
```